# How to define hide mode for tex \begin & \end in emacs auctex mode?

Tags: emacs, hide, directory, tex, auctex

I recently write a lot of tables in my tex documents. I would like to hide the table block when I am editing otherwise it will be messy.

here is the documents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
    \hline
    My & Name & is \\
    What's & your & name\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Since I am using Emacs with AucTeX (under windows7), I would like to hide table block as below:

```
\begin{table}...\end{table}
```

I am try to define

```
(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
             '(LaTeX-mode
               "\\\\begin" ;; regexp for start block
               "\\\\end"   ;; regexp for end block
               "%"         ;; regexp for comment start
               nil
               nil))
```

But I didn't get what I want. Can anyone help here? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

muede's right, auctex's folding functionality works very good. you can add environments to be folded customizing `TeX-fold-env-spec-list`, and give a string that should be shown as replacement, for example `[table]` (or even have it show on of the environment's arguments, so not all look the same).

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar feature already in Auctex, called folding.

```
(info "(auctex) Folding")
```

muede

Answer (score 0):

`hs-grok-mode-type` expects "latex" as major-mode. Also move-forward needs it's slot.

```
(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
                 '(latex-mode
                   "\\\\begin" ;; regexp for start block
                   "\\\\end"   ;; regexp for end block
                   "%"         ;; regexp for comment start
                   (lambda (arg)(search-forward "\\end"))
                   nil))
```